# async creating folder in nodejs

Tags: node.js, asynchronous

I tryed to make simple script that create a folder if it not exsists. I readed some articles and maked logic like this:

```
debug("before async");
(async () => {
  if(!fs.existsSync(outputPath)){
    debug("Folder not exsists! path: "+outputPath)
    try{
      return await fs.mkdir(outputPath)
    }catch(err){
      debug(err)
    }
  }
  res.send('<h1>Hello world!</h1>')
})()
```

I got an error:

```
(node:27611) [DEP0013] DeprecationWarning: Calling an asynchronous function without callback is deprecated.
```

Ok. I figured a little and remind that guy from stackoverflow tell me make callback functon as promisify. I tryed to make it:

```
const mkdir = util.promisify(fs.mkdir);
debug("Before async");
(async () => {
  if(!fs.existsSync(outputPath)){
    debug("Folder not exsists! path: "+outputPath)
    await Promise.all(mkdir(outputPath))
  }
  res.send('<h1>Hello world!</h1>')
})()
```

But I got other error:

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 3): TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

How was I supposed to make all? If you know any guides that can help me to understand about asynchronous functionality - that will be great. Thanks!

btw, both ways folder was created. but with errors...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Promise.all` is for running an array of promises. In your case, you can just do this:

```
await mkdir(outputPath)
```

Depending on your needs, you could potentially do something like this:

```
await Promise.all([mkdir(path1), mkdir(path2), mkdir(path3)])
```

I would recommend becoming familiar with callbacks and promises before jumping into async/await.

Answer (score 9):

Node 11.x.x and later

```
await fs.promises.mkdir( '/path/mydir' );
```

Answer (score 1):

You cant/dont need to use `Promise.all` as you only handling one promise anyway, just do

```
await mkdir(outputPath)
```

Besides that you really should add some error handling to your code.

Answer (score 0):

Asynchronously checking to see if a folder exists and then creating one if it doesn't. Works from Node.js ^10.20.1.

```
const fsPromises = require("fs").promises;

async function createDir(dir) {
  try {
    await fsPromises.access(dir, fs.constants.F_OK);
  } catch (e) {
    await fsPromises.mkdir(dir);
  }
}
```